# Is there any libraries or way to convert video (mp4, mov) to gif in React Native for both Android and iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm implementing the feature of video recording in React Native, and want to have the features of convert the video that recorded to GIF before send to server. Is there any libraries or ways to convert the video such as mp4, mov to gif in React Native for both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instal library

> npm install react-native-video-to-gif --save

2. Using lib

> import RNGif from 'react-native-video-to-gif';

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this library is only for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try FFMPEG

FFMPEG is known for all kinds of video manipulations. Including converting video to gif. And the package below is React-Native compatible, available on both iOS and Android.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg